# Proof that Category Product is a Category

Tags: category-theory

let A and B be categories, and let's define category product as:

$A \times B \;\;$ where:

$(1)$ the objects are pairs $(a, b)$ such that $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

$(2)$ the arrow work like $(f,g) : (A, B) \rightarrow (C, D)$ where:

- $f \in A, \;\;f:A \rightarrow C$
- $g \in B, \;\;f:B \rightarrow D$

$(3)$ the identity is defined as $\;1_{(A,B)} = (1_{A}, 1_{B})$

$(4)$ the composition is defined as $(f, g)\circ (f',g')$ = $(f\circ f',\;g\circ g')$

---

I think I should prove it like this:

1 - Prove that the identity is identity for composition operation

2 - Prove that the composition is associative.

---

[1] let $(f,g) = fg $

$fg = fg \circ 1_{(A,B)}$

so

$fg( (a,b) ) = fg \times 1_{(A,B)}(a,b)$

$fg( (a,b) ) = fg ((a,b))$

---

my questions are:

- do I have to prove what I said I should?
- is the identity proof correct?
- how can I prove associativity over composition?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you set $(f,g)=fg$? That looks like you're confusing a morphism $(f,g)$ in the product with the composition $fg$ of two morphisms in the same category. Due to this confusion, none of the rest of your argument makes sense. You need to prove, for any $(f,g):(A,B)\to (A',B'),$ that $(f,g)=(f,g)\circ 1_{A,B}=1_{A',B'}\circ (f,g)$.

The proof should look something like this:
$(f,g)\circ 1_{A,B}=(f,g)\circ (1_A,1_B)=(f\circ 1_A,g\circ 1_B)=(f,g)$, and similarly for sticking the identity on the other side. Then you should do the same kind of thing for associativity.

Comment: is just a notation, writing fg instead of (f,g), only for simplicity

Comment: OK, then what is $fg((a,b))$ supposed to mean?

Comment: the application of (f,g) on (a,b), that is (f(a), g(b)).

Comment: You're working in a category. There is no notion of an element, or of the application of a morphism to an element, available. What you're supposed to prove is the first line you wrote! That is, $fg=fg\circ 1_{A,B}$.

Comment: sorry for mistakes, I've just been introduced to categories and prove this things or fix this wrong notions are not that easy for me yet

Answer (score -1):

Associativity is a statement about three morphisms, so it doesn't look like you've checked that here.  The statements are true and the definition is standard; see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/product+category

Comment: no use in this answer yet... I know what associativity is and the link just shows the same I wrote in question's description